# Managing Data to Highcharts from Webservice

Tags: c#, json, highcharts

I used to get my data from database and then, I pass the data in a Json and Push it in a array to use on Highcharts.

Now, I have a new way to get the data, from a webservice and im quite confuse in how can I pass the data.

**Old way from DATABASE**

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult EsperaHora(string data1, string data2, int? cliente)
{

     var voiceData = new KiperVoiceData(cliente);
     var media = voiceData.GetEsperaData(data1, data2);
     var atend = voiceData.GetEsperaHora(data1, data2);
     var result = new { atend, media };

     return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**[image: Data Return]**

ON JS File

```
 $.ajax({
            url: '/KiperVoice/EsperaHora',
            dataType: "json",
            type: "GET",
            data: { 'data1': data1, 'data2': data2, 'cliente': cliente },
            success: function (data) {

                    var Categories = new Array();
                    var Series = new Array();
                    var Series2 = new Array();
                    var media = data.media;
                    var total = 0;

                    for (var i in data.atend) {
                        Categories.push(data.atend[i].Hora);
                        Series.push(data.atend[i].Espera);
                        Series2.push(data.atend[i].Qtde);
                        total += parseInt(data.atend[i].Qtde);
                    }

                    $('#media').val(media);
                    $('#total').val(total);

                    var HoraArray = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(Categories));
                    atendHora(HoraArray, Series);
                    atendQtde(HoraArray, Series2);
                }
            },
```

Its working very fine, but now, I need to get de data from a Webservice Json like Below:

NEW way from Json

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult EsperaHora3(string data1, string data2, int? cliente)
{             
   string WEBSERVICE_URL = "http://187.49.236.29:3010/report/waithour?from=" + data1 + "&to=" + data2 + "&queue=Base";

    var webRequest = WebRequest.Create(WEBSERVICE_URL);

    if (webRequest != null)
        {
           webRequest.Method = "GET";
           webRequest.Timeout = 20000;
           webRequest.ContentType = "application/json";

            using (System.IO.Stream s = webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
                {
                    using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(s))
                       {
                          var jsonResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<APIVoice>>(sr.ReadToEnd());    

                        }
                    }
                }


                return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
```

[image: Json Data]

```
    [{"key":"10:00","value":{"total":2,"avg":20}},
    {"key":"11:00","value":{"total":4,"avg":25.5}},
    {"key":"14:00","value":{"total":3,"avg":5.33}]
```

Where:

```
Key = Hora
Qtde = total
Espera = avg
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution!!!

```
  $.ajax({
            url: '/KiperVoice/EsperaHora3',
            dataType: "json",
            type: "GET",
            data: { 'data1': data1, 'data2': data2, 'cliente': cliente },
            success: function (data) {

                    var Categories = new Array();
                    var Series = new Array();
                    var Series2 = new Array();


                    for (var i in data) {

                        Categories.push(data[i].Key);
                        Series.push(parseInt(data[i].value.avg));
                        Series2.push(data[i].value.total);

                    }                 

                    var HoraArray = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(Categories));
                    atendHora(HoraArray, Series);
                    atendQtde(HoraArray, Series2);
                }
            },
```

It´s was isiest I thought!!!